# The canvas does not work in mobile

Tags: javascript, image-processing, mobile, canvas, ionic-framework

I built an app based on *Ionic Framework*, and I use canvas to do the image crop. It works well in browser:

[image]

But I found it does not work when running in the mobile:

[image]

Anyone knows why?

Comment: It caused by the image got from the phone was a file, but my code only worked with base64 data url. So I updated my code and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it does not work but people have made some awesome image crop modules in angular that do work. I am using on in a company app to assist in document scanning. This is the one I used and it works flawlessly, you can choose your crop shape, size, ect. Get it here: https://github.com/jodonnell-broadsoft/JsImageCrop
This is what the code looks like:

```
                <div class="item item-image cropArea">
                    <img-Crop image="image.uncropped" result-image="image.cropped" result-image-format="image/png" area-type="rectangle" on-change="console.log($scope.image.cropped)">

                    </img-Crop>
                </div>
```

and what it looks like one the phone:

[image]